# Json Error typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue:

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
import UIKit
import Foundation


class ViewController: UIViewController{
    
    

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var movies = [MoviesModel]()
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getJson {
            print("successfully")
        }
        
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    func getJson(completed: @escaping () -> ()){
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json")
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {
            (data,response,error) in
            
            if error == nil {
                do{
                    self.movies = try

                        JSONDecoder().decode([MoviesModel].self,from:data!)
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completed()
                        
                    }
                }catch{
                    print("Json Error  \(error)")
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }


}
```

who can help me to solve this error

> Json Error  typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "releaseYear", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Please **read** the error message, it clearly says that the **value** for **key** **`releaseYear`** is a **number** (an integer) rather than a string.

Comment: yeah that’s right i’m really didnt notice that i was really tired of college stuff , thank you @Vadian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest spending more time understanding what's happening in the code that you posted, going through a brief overview:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let decodedMovies = decoder.decode([MoviesModel].self, from:data!)
```

Here you are trying to decode the data that is received from the request to movies request. Not entirely sure how your model looks, but it does seem like you want to define it like the following:

```
struct MoviesModel: Codable {
  let title: String
  let image: String
  let rating: Double
  let releaseYear: Int
  let genre: [String]
}
```

Which should help to solve your decoding issues, as described in the error that you are posting.

Please also check Apple documentation on the subject - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Comment: my moviesModel look like that exactly

Comment: i just was defined the releaseYear as String not Int